# HTML and CSS multiple tables display problem

Tags: html, css

I need help, how I can remove this space below the tables? 
I want to have 3 tables in 1 row and below also 3 tables in 1 row etc.. I've been trying for a few days but I can't succeed. :( 
I hope you understand me, any help is welcome .

Each new table in a new row depends on the previous table row which has several rows and it includes the same height.

Each new table in a new row depends on the previous table row which has several rows and it includes the same height.

```css
<style type="text/css">

table {
   width: 100%;
}

td:hover {
   background-color: #6E6E6E;
}

/* -------------------------Table 1 CSS-------------------------*/
table.table1 {
   width: 33.33%;
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.table1 tr {
   width: 33.33%;
}

table.table1 th {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #b45f04; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
   border-top: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-left: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-right: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #FAAC58;
}

table.table1 td {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 8px;
   text-align: center; 
   color: #D8D8D8;
   background-color: #585858;
   border-left: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-right: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #848484;
}

table.table1 tr:last-child td:last-child { 
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* -------------------------Table 2 CSS-------------------------*/
table.table2 {
   width: 33.33%;
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.table2 tr {
   width: 33.33%;
}

table.table2 th {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #b45f04; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
   border-top: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-left: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-right: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #FAAC58;
}

table.table2 td {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 8px;
   text-align: center; 
   color: #D8D8D8;
   background-color: #585858;
   border-left: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-right: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #848484;
}

table.table2 tr:last-child td:last-child { 
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* -------------------------Table 3 CSS-------------------------*/
table.table3 {
   width: 33.33%;
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.table3 tr {
   width: 33.33%;
}

table.table3 th {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #b45f04; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
   border-top: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-left: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-right: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #FAAC58;
}

table.table3 td {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 8px;
   text-align: center; 
   color: #D8D8D8;
   background-color: #585858;
   border-left: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-right: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #848484;
}

table.table3 tr:last-child td:last-child { 
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* -------------------------Table 4 CSS-------------------------*/
table.table4 {
   width: 33.33%;
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.table4 tr {
   width: 33.33%;
}

table.table4 th {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #b45f04; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
   border-top: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-left: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-right: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #FAAC58;
}

table.table4 td {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 8px;
   text-align: center; 
   color: #D8D8D8;
   background-color: #585858;
   border-left: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-right: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #848484;
}

table.table4 tr:last-child td:last-child { 
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* -------------------------Table 5 CSS-------------------------*/
table.table5 {
   width: 33.33%;
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.table5 tr {
   width: 33.33%;
}

table.table5 th {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #b45f04; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
   border-top: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-left: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-right: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #FAAC58;
}

table.table5 td {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 8px;
   text-align: center; 
   color: #D8D8D8;
   background-color: #585858;
   border-left: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-right: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #848484;
}

table.table5 tr:last-child td:last-child { 
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* -------------------------Table 6 CSS-------------------------*/
table.table6 {
   width: 33.33%;
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.table6 tr {
   width: 33.33%;
}

table.table6 th {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #b45f04; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
   border-top: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-left: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-right: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #FAAC58;
}

table.table6 td {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 8px;
   text-align: center; 
   color: #D8D8D8;
   background-color: #585858;
   border-left: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-right: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #848484;
}

table.table6 tr:last-child td:last-child { 
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* -------------------------Table 7 CSS-------------------------*/
table.table7 {
   width: 33.33%;   
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.table7 tr {
   width: 33.33%;
}

table.table7 th {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #b45f04; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
   border-top: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-left: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-right: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #FAAC58;
}

table.table7 td {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 8px;
   text-align: center; 
   color: #D8D8D8;
   background-color: #585858;
   border-left: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-right: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #848484;
}

table.table7 tr:last-child td:last-child { 
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* -------------------------Table 8 CSS-------------------------*/
table.table8 {
   width: 33.33%;   
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.table8 tr {
   width: 33.33%;
}

table.table8 th {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #b45f04; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
   border-top: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-left: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-right: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #FAAC58;
}

table.table8 td {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 8px;
   text-align: center; 
   color: #D8D8D8;
   background-color: #585858;
   border-left: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-right: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #848484;
}

table.table8 tr:last-child td:last-child { 
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* -------------------------Table 9 CSS-------------------------*/
table.table9 {
   width: 33.33%;   
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.table9 tr {
   width: 33.33%;
}

table.table9 th {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #b45f04; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
   border-top: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-left: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-right: 3px solid #FAAC58; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #FAAC58;
}

table.table9 td {
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 8px;
   text-align: center; 
   color: #D8D8D8;
   background-color: #585858;
   border-left: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-right: 3px solid #848484; 
   border-bottom: 3px solid #848484;
}

table.table9 tr:last-child td:last-child { 
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
/* -------------------------------------------------------------*/

</style>
```

```html
<table class="table1">
    <tbody>
       <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table2">
   <tbody>
        <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table3">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table4">
    <tbody>
         <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table5">
     <tbody>
          <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table6">
    <tbody>
         <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table7">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table8">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 
<table class="table9">
   <tbody>
        <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
       <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you share an image of what you want to achieve. What you describe is not easy to understand.

Comment: Maybe you can see now, I edited snipped code. Just I want to have my tables below like side by side (without any space and only with margins) if you understand me

Comment: Do you want each row of tables to be the same height

Comment: Yes like in this code. But you see 3rd table height change 4th table height and 4th table must be in same line like 3rd table, i don't want this :'( I want 4th table to put under 1st table in normal space. (space like in table 3rd and 6th)
sorry for my bad english, i hope you understand me

Comment: You can draw a image. Used to describe the requirements you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are putting the `<th>` tag which corresponds to the table head, in the `<tbody>` section, which is wrong.
You must put the `<th>` in the missing `<thead>` tag ..

**The correct form of a table :**

```
    <table class="table1">
      <thead>
        <tr><th> TABLE HEADER </th></tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr><td> Table Rows</td><tr>
     <tr><td> Table Rows</td><tr>
     <tr><td> Table Rows</td><tr>
     <tr><td> Table Rows</td><tr>
     <tr><td> Table Rows</td><tr>
     <tr><td> Table Rows</td><tr>
     <tr><td> Table Rows</td><tr>
     <tr><td> Table Rows</td><tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Still same.

btw I edited snippet code, it's seen better now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for but check it out-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="masonry">
        <div class="item">
            <table class="table1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <table class="table2">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <table class="table3">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <table class="table4">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <table class="table5">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <table class="table6">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <table class="table7">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <table class="table8">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <table class="table9">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>TABLE HEADER EXAMPLE</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Table Rows Example</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        Run code snippet
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the basic css needed just for layout -

```
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

.item { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Note: this layout renders items in top-to-bottom manner. For more details, you can check-
https://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: not work but i think this is it, this just needs to be configured but it is very hard :(

Comment: you code work fine but I can't control tables, how I can control which table is on left middle or right side because I use 3 tables in 1 row? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The order in which you write your tables in html and the top-bottom rendering manner of this layout decides the order. Do you have control on the order of tables you are writing in html ? or is like dynamically generated? Also if you want your layout in left-to-right manner, the link provided has that solution as well.
https://w3bits.com/css-grid-masonry/